# Get parameter of template in Play Framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters, playframework, playframework-2.1

I have a template with parameter like this :

```
@(people: List[models.Person])
<html>
<head>      
</head>
<body>
<table class="centered" id="table_people">
 <thead>
   <tr class="table_header">
        <th></th>
        <th class="people_column">Name</th>
        <th class="people_column">Active</th> 
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>     
    @for(p <- people) {
     <tr>
        <td><button id="timesheet_view_" >View</button</td>
        <td><b>@p.getName()</b></td>
        <td>@p.isActive()</td>          
    </tr>           
   }
</tbody>
</table>
```

That code shows a list of people. And now, i wanna when click on button view, it shows information of people. To do that, i have to write something like that:

```
    <script>
    $( "#timesheet_view_<%= people[i].id %>" )
      .button()
      .click(function() {
         people = '<%= people[i].name %>';
         showTimeSheet('current', '<%= people[i].name    %>');              
            })
   </script>
```

But i can't find how to get value people parameter of template in Javascript. I try to use @ character, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to fix your HTML code: 
`<td><button id="timesheet_view_" >View</button</td>`:
close the button element correctly: `</button` with a '**>**'.

Second, you have to give every button a unique ID:

Your code:

```
@for(p <- people) {
  <tr>
    <td><button id="timesheet_view_" >View</button</td>
    <td><b>@p.getName()</b></td>
    <td>@p.isActive()</td>          
  </tr>           
}
```

Try it with:

```
@for(p <- people) {
  <tr>
    <td><button id="timesheet_view_@p.id">View</button></td>
    <td><b>@p.getName()</b></td>
    <td>@p.isActive()</td>          
  </tr>           
}

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // There are better ways to do this, but it's just for your example
    @for(p <- people) {
      $("#timesheet_view_@p.id").click(function(e) {
        ... // your javascript code here
      });
    }
  });
</script>
```

In my opinion it's better to use a link here (instead of a button), because for every button you need to code extra javascript for the onclick event. Try it with a link and Play! will do the work for you:

```
@for(p <- people) {
  <tr>
    <td><a class="btn" href="@routes.Application.view(p.id)">View</a></td>
    <td><b>@p.getName()</b></td>
    <td>@p.isActive()</td>          
  </tr>           
}
```

Btw, if you use Twitter Bootstrap you can use `class="btn"` and your link looks like a button.

Start your Play! application and have a look in the HTML source code. You will see your code `<button id="timesheet_view_@p.id">View</button>` will looks like this:

`<button id="timesheet_view_1">View</button>`

`<button id="timesheet_view_2">View</button>`

...

`<button id="timesheet_view_9">View</button>`

Hope this helps.

Best regards,
gfjr

Comment: i dont think your answer is correct , the people parameter is not avail to the script tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it that way. Javascript is running client-side whereas Play is running server-side.

At the time your Javascript is running, the page has already been rendered and Play has done it's part.

What you can do is to capture relevant data from `people` and put it in data attributes.

```
<tbody>     
  @for(p <- people) {
    <tr data-people-id="@p.getId()" data-people-name="@p.getName()">
      <td><button class="timesheet_view" >View</button</td>
      <td><b>@p.getName()</b></td>
      <td>@p.isActive()</td>          
    </tr>           
  }
</tbody>
```

And in your script you can get the data attributes.

```
<script>
  $( ".timesheet_view" )
    .button()
    .click(function() {
      var row = $(this).closest("tr");
      var peopleId = row.data("peopleId");
      var peopleName = row.data("peopleName");
      // Do whatever you want with this data...
      // Not sure how the showTimeSheet is working so leave it up to you
      //showTimeSheet('current', '<%= people[i].name    %>');              
  });
</script>
```